# How to know the detail information of all buffer pages (like the address, timestamp ...) for a SQL Server database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have kept searching for the answers of this problem on the internet. But I can only find answers of getting the total number of pages for a database.

What I want to know is to list the address and time stamp of all pages for a database. I think there might be a DMV which stores this information but I can not figure out which one it is. Can anyone help?

Comment: There's an undocumented DBCC command: DBCC PAGE. Take a look at [Using DBCC PAGE](http://sqlmag.com/database-administration/using-dbcc-page) it will at least be able to display the page address for you, however I am not sure about the timestamp (timestamp of the page creation is what you're looking for?)

Comment: Yes, I am trying to know the time of the page creation. Thanks for your information.

Comment: I did a little googling ("DBCC PAGE metadata timestamp") and got [this](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/inside-the-storage-engine-anatomy-of-a-record/).  It says that the timestamp is only available in SQL Server 2005, but it looks like it was written pre-2008, so it's probably still available in the same offset location in later versions.  Anyway, this might get you a bit further down the road.

Comment: Thanks Bob, that is helpful.